# How do I integrate my food order menu to Uber eat delivery service?

Tags: uber-api

API endpoints?
I need information about the get/post/put/del and authorization.

How do the customer order?
After customer paid and he/she choose Uber eat service, does he/she pick from my website or from the Uber eat app?

How does the customer pay? How does the business owner get paid? What kind of payment service can they use?

Comment: Head to https://www.ubereats.com/restaurant/en-US/signup and sign up. They'll guide you through the process. Consider placing your own order from a local restaurant via UberEats so you know how it works - half of your questions are probably answerable that way.